# Rollback notice is not used from Transifex

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, localization

Seems that "Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator" message translation is not used from Transifex in the revision list. I've [made translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5464/176217) about 3 months ago, but it's [not used yet](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5807/176217).

Comment: Since this affect all localized sites, not only Russian.SO please don't use this tag. That tag is for things related **only** to that site, and since those are better posted in the site meta and will be closed here, the tag better not be used at all.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I use this tag when I found issue on ruSO and that issue can't be fixed inside ruSO community only (i.e. without actions from SO devs). Current [tag:russian-stackoverflow] tag description says nothing about using for **only** ruSO specific questions. I can't check every issue in all localized SOs before posting here. If in the result of research it becomes clear that issue related for another sites tag could be removed. However when I post issue and it's related to ruSO I will tag it with appropriate tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long story short, when a suggested edit is overridden, we store that information as a comment in English in the database.

As of a few minutes ago, we're going to replace that comment with the localized version when generating revision descriptions. This way any other changes to the translation will be reflected on the past and future edit overrides.

Comment: Thanks for quick fix. Could you also look at [another](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3735/176217) bug report?

Comment: @alexolut Sure, I'll take a look. At first glance, it looks like a similar issue but in a different area of code. I don't know if I'll have time today, but I'll try to get to it soon.

Comment: I will wait for your responce. Thanks again in advance.